# Power in Center of Gravity

Tags: phonetics, praat

I am writing a Praat script to measure center of gravity in fricatives. I don't understand what the difference is in the power values. The [manual](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Spectrum__Get_centre_of_gravity___.html) says "Common values are 2, 1, or 2/3", but I don't understand what that means for my measurements, exactly. Which value is useful for measuring what? Or, what values are useful in what situations? Thank you.

Comment: Using a power>1 emphasizes the difference in loudness between the frequencies, giving more weight to the louder, while a power<1 gives less weight to loudness.